# The controller with name is not registered when loading the html through template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, ngroute, ng-view

I am currently trying to change my web app from routing through mvc to SPA, where all different will be loaded in single main page. For this I am using ngview directive. This is the main page -

```
<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
       var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "Experimental/Index.html",
                controller:"AddressList"

            })

        });

</script>

}
```

For now I only have one route. my controller is defined in a script tag inside the Index.html file itself and not in a seperate .js file like so -

```
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('AddressList', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.model = [];
        $http.get('/Addresses/GetAddresses').then(function (response) {
            if (response != null || response != "undefined") {
                $scope.model = response.data;
            }
        });

    }]);
```

But after load of the main page I am getting an error message  -

> The controller with name 'AddressList' is not registered.

Does this mean I have to keep all my controllers in seperate files or inside the main html?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your code. It would be much easier to debug.

Comment: The AngularJS framework ignores controllers defined in `templateUrl` files. All controllers need to be defined before the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 reasons to **not registered message** in Angularjs:

1. The source is not defined in your app

   ```
   <script defer src="angular.js"></script>
   <script defer src="app.js"></script> <!-- app.module(...) -->
   <script defer src="controller.js"></script> <!-- app.controller(...) -->
   ```
2. Register controller in your app config, *this happens when you load controllers as lazy*

> **Note:** Not different if you have a separate file for your controller or inline script

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.config(function($controllerProvider){
    app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
})
```